# xterm not displaying unicode

Tags: xterm, unicode

i have never been able to get my terminal to display unicode symbols. for example, before i had my present os, i mapped ctrl+a to the greek mu in vim, and it works on other computers, but not on my current xterm. here is the relevant section of my `.vimrc`:

```
set encoding=utf-8
"map control-a to mu
imap <C-a> <C-k>m*
```

also, i need to output sympy equations in python, and this works on other computers, but not on my current xterm. instead of this:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 14 2014, 11:57:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sympy
>>> x = sympy.symbols('x')
>>> sympy.init_printing()
>>> (sympy.sqrt(x**3/(x+1)), 1)
⎛     _______   ⎞
⎜    ╱    3     ⎟
⎜   ╱    x      ⎟
⎜  ╱   ───── , 1⎟
⎝╲╱    x + 1    ⎠
```

i get this:

```
>>> (sympy.sqrt(x**3/(x+1)), 1)
n      -------   n
n     n    3     n
n    n    x      n
n   n   ───── , 1n
nnnn    x + 1    n
```

infact it seems to just use the `n` character whenever it can't display a unicode character.

i'm running xterm from an `~/.xinitrc` file and setting some fonts and colors for the terminal in `~/.Xresources`. here is all the relevant information i could think of:

```
$ uname -a
Linux mypcname 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.60-1+deb7u3 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ xterm -version
XTerm(278)
$ cat ~/.xinitrc 
#!/bin/bash

#update the xterm colors, font size, etc
[[ -f ~/.Xresources ]] && xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources

# run the window manager in the background first
metacity &

# get the window manager process id
wm_pid=$!

# wait a little while for the window manager to load (extend this if the xterm is not being properly maximised)
sleep 2

# run the xterm in fullscreen
#xterm +u8 -js -fullscreen &
xterm -en en_AU.UTF-8 -js -fullscreen &

# do not let the window manager become a zombie
wait $wm_pid

# this would run xterm first, then the window manager. doesn't maximise properly the first time startx is run
#xterm -fullscreen &
#exec mutter

$ cat ~/.Xresources 
! see man xterm under the resources heading for explanations
! run `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources` after altering this file
! run `xrdb -query -all` to see the current settings

xterm.vt100.faceName: Terminus
xterm.vt100.faceSize: 14
! do not display bold fonts in bold
xterm.vt100.AllowBoldFonts: false
! display bold fonts in a different color to make them stand out
xterm.vt100.colorBDMode: true
! use green as the bold color (same as in ~/.bashrc)
xterm.vt100.colorBD: #98E34D

! cols x lines ... update with values from $(echo $COLUMNS) and $(echo $LINES)
xterm.vt100.geometry: 126x52

! dark green foreground (same as in ~/.bashrc)
*foreground: #4E9A06
! black background
*background: #000000

! scroll quickly
xterm*fastScroll: true

! enable utf-8 encoding
xterm*locale: true
xterm*utf8: 1

! flash the current line instead of making the bell sound
*visualBell: true
*visualBellLine: true

! black
*color0: #2E3436
! darkred
*color1: #CC0000
! dark green
*color2: #4E9A06
! brown
*color3: #C4A000
! darkblue
*color4: #3465A4
! darkmagenta
*color5: #75507B
! darkcyan
*color6: #06989A
! lightgrey
*color7: #D3D7CF
! darkgrey
*color8: #555753
! red
*color9: #EF2929
! green
*colorA: #8AE234
! yellow
*colorB: #FCE94F
! blue
*colorC: #729FCF
! magenta
*colorD: #AD7FA8
! cyan
*colorE: #34E2E2
! white
*colorF: #EEEEEC

$ tail -10 .bashrc
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin

export LC_ALL=en_AU.UTF-8
export LANG=en_AU.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_AU.UTF-8

# final logon actions:

# go straight to x on login. only do this for tty1 so that we can still use the other tty consoles without starting x. also only do this when there is not already a display, otherwise the xterm will try and do this after x starts aswell
[[ -z $DISPLAY ]] && [[ $(tty) = /dev/tty1 ]] && startx

$ locale
LANG=en_AU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_AU.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_AU.UTF-8

$ printenv XTERM_LOCALE
en_AU.UTF-8

$ xrdb -query -all
*background:    #000000
*color0:    #2E3436
*color1:    #CC0000
*color2:    #4E9A06
*color3:    #C4A000
*color4:    #3465A4
*color5:    #75507B
*color6:    #06989A
*color7:    #D3D7CF
*color8:    #555753
*color9:    #EF2929
*colorA:    #8AE234
*colorB:    #FCE94F
*colorC:    #729FCF
*colorD:    #AD7FA8
*colorE:    #34E2E2
*colorF:    #EEEEEC
*foreground:    #4E9A06
*visualBell:    true
*visualBellLine:    true
xterm*fastScroll:   true
xterm*locale:   true
xterm*utf8: 1
xterm.vt100.AllowBoldFonts: false
xterm.vt100.colorBD:    #98E34D
xterm.vt100.colorBDMode:    true
xterm.vt100.faceName:   Terminus
xterm.vt100.faceSize:   14
xterm.vt100.geometry:   126x52
```

**how can i get utf-8 working to display greek symbols in vim and equations in `sympy`?**

---

extra information requested

```
$ echo $TERM
xterm
$ appres XTerm
*form.Thickness:    0
*tekMenu*tekreset*Label:    RESET
*tekMenu*tektext2*Label:    #2 Size Characters
*tekMenu*tekhide*Label: Hide Tek Window
*tekMenu*tekcopy*Label: COPY
*tekMenu*tektext3*Label:    #3 Size Characters
*tekMenu*vtshow*Label:  Show VT Window
*tekMenu*tektextsmall*Label:    Small Characters
*tekMenu*vtmode*Label:  Switch to VT Mode
*tekMenu*tektextlarge*Label:    Large Characters
*tekMenu*tekpage*Label: PAGE
*tekMenu.Label: Tek Options
*mainMenu*redraw*Label: Redraw Window
*mainMenu*sunKeyboard*Label:    VT220 Keyboard
*mainMenu*terminate*Label:  Send TERM Signal
*mainMenu*backarrow key*Label:  Backarrow Key (BS/DEL)
*mainMenu*logging*Label:    Log to File
*mainMenu*hpFunctionKeys*Label: HP Function-Keys
*mainMenu*kill*Label:   Send KILL Signal
*mainMenu*num-lock*Label:   Alt/NumLock Modifiers
*mainMenu*print-immediate*Label:    Print-All Immediately
*mainMenu*scoFunctionKeys*Label:    SCO Function-Keys
*mainMenu*quit*Label:   Quit
*mainMenu*alt-esc*Label:    Alt Sends Escape
*mainMenu*print-on-error*Label: Print-All on Error
*mainMenu*tcapFunctionKeys*Label:   Termcap Function-Keys
*mainMenu*meta-esc*Label:   Meta Sends Escape
*mainMenu*toolbar*Label:    Toolbar
*mainMenu*print*Label:  Print Window
*mainMenu*suspend*Label:    Send STOP Signal
*mainMenu*delete-is-del*Label:  Delete is DEL
*mainMenu*print-redir*Label:    Redirect to Printer
*mainMenu*fullscreen*Label: Full Screen
*mainMenu*continue*Label:   Send CONT Signal
*mainMenu*oldFunctionKeys*Label:    Old Function-Keys
*mainMenu*securekbd*Label:  Secure Keyboard
*mainMenu*interrupt*Label:  Send INT Signal
*mainMenu*8-bit control*Label:  8-Bit Controls
*mainMenu*allowsends*Label: Allow SendEvents
*mainMenu*sunFunctionKeys*Label:    Sun Function-Keys
*mainMenu*hangup*Label: Send HUP Signal
*mainMenu.Label:    Main Options
*VT100.utf8Fonts.font4: -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--13-120-75-75-c-80-iso10646-1
*VT100.utf8Fonts.font2: -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--8-80-75-75-c-50-iso10646-1
*VT100.utf8Fonts.font6: -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--20-200-75-75-c-100-iso10646-1
*VT100.utf8Fonts.font5: -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--18-120-100-100-c-90-iso10646-1
*VT100.utf8Fonts.font3: -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--14-130-75-75-c-70-iso10646-1
*VT100.utf8Fonts.font:  -misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso10646-1
*VT100.font4:   7x13
*VT100.font2:   5x7
*VT100.font6:   10x20
*VT100.font5:   9x15
*VT100.font3:   6x10
*VT100.font1:   nil2
*vtMenu*selectToClipboard*Label:    Select to Clipboard
*vtMenu*reversewrap*Label:  Enable Reverse Wraparound
*vtMenu*softreset*Label:    Do Soft Reset
*vtMenu*cursesemul*Label:   Enable Curses Emulation
*vtMenu*autolinefeed*Label: Enable Auto Linefeed
*vtMenu*hardreset*Label:    Do Full Reset
*vtMenu*visualbell*Label:   Enable Visual Bell
*vtMenu*appcursor*Label:    Enable Application Cursor Keys
*vtMenu*clearsavedlines*Label:  Reset and Clear Saved Lines
*vtMenu*bellIsUrgent*Label: Enable Bell Urgency
*vtMenu*appkeypad*Label:    Enable Application Keypad
*vtMenu*tekshow*Label:  Show Tek Window
*vtMenu*poponbell*Label:    Enable Pop on Bell
*vtMenu*scrollbar*Label:    Enable Scrollbar
*vtMenu*scrollkey*Label:    Scroll to Bottom on Key Press
*vtMenu*tekmode*Label:  Switch to Tek Mode
*vtMenu*scrollttyoutput*Label:  Scroll to Bottom on Tty Output
*vtMenu*jumpscroll*Label:   Enable Jump Scroll
*vtMenu*cursorblink*Label:  Enable Blinking Cursor
*vtMenu*vthide*Label:   Hide VT Window
*vtMenu*allow132*Label: Allow 80/132 Column Switching
*vtMenu*reversevideo*Label: Enable Reverse Video
*vtMenu*titeInhibit*Label:  Enable Alternate Screen Switching
*vtMenu*altscreen*Label:    Show Alternate Screen
*vtMenu*keepSelection*Label:    Keep Selection
*vtMenu*autowrap*Label: Enable Auto Wraparound
*vtMenu*activeicon*Label:   Enable Active Icon
*vtMenu.Label:  VT Options
*SimpleMenu*menuLabel.font: -adobe-helvetica-bold-r-normal--*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*
*SimpleMenu*menuLabel.vertSpace:    100
*SimpleMenu*Sme.height: 16
*SimpleMenu*BackingStore:   NotUseful
*SimpleMenu*HorizontalMargins:  16
*SimpleMenu*Cursor: left_ptr
*SimpleMenu*borderWidth:    2
*menubar.borderWidth:   0
*tek4014*fontLarge: 9x15
*tek4014*font2: 8x13
*tek4014*font3: 6x13
*tek4014*fontSmall: 6x10
*MenuButton*borderWidth:    0
*fontMenu*render-font*Label:    TrueType Fonts
*fontMenu*fontdefault*Label:    Default
*fontMenu*font6*Label:  Huge
*fontMenu*allow-window-ops*Label:   Allow Window Ops
*fontMenu*utf8-mode*Label:  UTF-8 Encoding
*fontMenu*font1*Label:  Unreadable
*fontMenu*fontescape*Label: Escape Sequence
*fontMenu*utf8-fonts*Label: UTF-8 Fonts
*fontMenu*fontsel*Label:    Selection
*fontMenu*allow-bold-fonts*Label:   Bold Fonts
*fontMenu*utf8-title*Label: UTF-8 Titles
*fontMenu*font-linedrawing*Label:   Line-Drawing Characters
*fontMenu*font2*Label:  Tiny
*fontMenu*allow-color-ops*Label:    Allow Color Ops
*fontMenu*font-doublesize*Label:    Doublesized Characters
*fontMenu*font3*Label:  Small
*fontMenu*allow-font-ops*Label: Allow Font Ops
*fontMenu*font-loadable*Label:  VT220 Soft Fonts
*fontMenu*font4*Label:  Medium
*fontMenu*allow-tcap-ops*Label: Allow Termcap Ops
*fontMenu*font-packed*Label:    Packed Font
*fontMenu*font5*Label:  Large
*fontMenu*allow-title-ops*Label:    Allow Title Ops
*fontMenu.Label:    VT Fonts
*colorD:    #AD7FA8
*color5:    #75507B
*backarrowKeyIsErase:   true
*colorE:    #34E2E2
*color6:    #06989A
*ptyInitialErase:   true
*colorF:    #EEEEEC
*background:    #000000
*color7:    #D3D7CF
*saveLines: 1024
*color8:    #555753
*color0:    #2E3436
*foreground:    #4E9A06
*IconFont:  nil2
*color9:    #EF2929
*color1:    #CC0000
*visualBell:    true
*colorA:    #8AE234
*color2:    #4E9A06
*visualBellLine:    true
*colorB:    #FCE94F
*color3:    #C4A000
*colorC:    #729FCF
*color4:    #3465A4
$ xterm -u8 -fa "DejaVu Sans Mono"
# the following is typed in the resulting terminal:
$ echo -e "\xE2\x98\xA0"
n
# however when i copy the result from `echo -e "\xE2\x98\xA0"`
# into my browser, i get this: ☠ (a skull) but it does not show
# up as a skull in my xterm

$ lsof -p $PPID | grep fonts
xterm   5990 me  mem    REG              254,1     4971 13501810 /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc/ter-u18b_iso-8859-1.pcf.gz
xterm   5990 me  mem    REG              254,1     4897 13505403 /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc/ter-u18n_iso-8859-1.pcf.gz
```

i also ran `$ fc-list` but the output was too large to paste into this question. so i have put it [here](https://github.com/mulllhausen/sysadmin-notes/blob/master/xterm-font-problems1)

what it shows in my browser:

```
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSansBold.ttf: FreeSans:style=Bold,получерен,negreta,tučné,fed,Fett,Έντονα,Negrita,Lihavoitu,Gras,Félkövér,Grassetto,Vet,Halvfet,Pogrubiony,Negrito,gros,Полужирный,Fet,Kalın,huruf tebal,жирний,Krepko,treknraksts,pusjuodis,đậm,Lodia,धृष्ट
```

what i see in my terminal:

```
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSansBold.ttf: FreeSans:style=Bold,nnnnnnnnn,negreta,tunné,fed,Fett,nnnnnn,Negrita,Lihavoitu,Gras,Félkövér,Grassetto,Vet,Halvfet,Pogrubiony,Negrito,gros,nnnnnnnnnn,Fet,Kalın,huruf tebal,nnnnnn,Krepko,treknraksts,pusjuodis,nậm,Lodia,nnn
```

interestingly, some "special" characters do show up in my terminal, but most are relaced by `n`. you can see in the previous output that none of `получерен` can be displayed, but the final character of `tučné` can be displayed (while the middle `č` cannot - it is replaced by `n`)

---

as per @apaul's comments it seems that xterm isn't loading the right font. try to set a dummy class so it doesn't load the xterm resources:

```
$ xterm -class Foo -name foo -u8 -fa "DejaVu Sans Mono:style=Book"
$ # the following commands are all executed in the resulting terminal:
$ echo -e "\xE2\x98\xA0"
☠
$ # the above skull actually shows up now. and so does the unicode
$ # output from sympy and also vi can display greek symbols now :)
```

all that remains is to figure out why xterm cannot set the font using `~/.Xresoureces`, and to get this working. it seems like something must be overriding the font settings?

actually i just thought to try above command with the terminus font, and it seems that this is the problem:

```
$ xterm -class Foo -name foo -u8 -fa "Terminus"
$ # the following commands are all executed in the resulting terminal:
$ echo -e "\xE2\x98\xA0"
n
```

maybe terminus is not properly installed? or is being mapped to something else. how could i find that out?

Comment: xterm doesn't support full UTF-8(AFAIK), try running uxterm, but I would recommend trying a different terminal such as urxvt, termite or st

Comment: rxvt-unicode works :)

Comment: @mulllhausen : Ctrl-RightClick in your xterm, do UTF-8 and Doublesized chars are "ticked" ?

Comment: @apaul i never knew about that! anyway, they were all ticked except for  `utf-8 titles` and it doesn't seem to have made a difference ticking it. i'm wondering if its my choice of terminus font that's not working. lots of places say that xterm supports utf8

Comment: @mulllhausen I confirm it should work. I use xterm for years and can display quite anything depending on the font. Terminus is able to display your example. I'm using `-fa "DejaVu Sans Mono:size=11:antialias=true"` However, I don't understand your `-js` and `-fullscreen` options. My version of xterm doesn't understand them. My `xterm -version` outputs `X.Org 6.8.99.903(253)`.

Comment: i'm using xterm(278). i will add it to the op.

Comment: Have you tried to run `xterm -u8` ? (I saw you tried `+u8`  which is the opposite)

Comment: @apaul i just tried it now. it doesn't work but the output from `sympy` is garbled in a different way - there are lots of `�`(a with a circumflex) characters instead of `n`s

Comment: p.s. the `-js` are just scrolling options. `-j` is jumpscrolling and `-s` is asynchronous scrolling. you can find them in `man xterm`

Comment: @mulllhausen can you tell the output of `echo $TERM` and `appres XTerm` (mind the case)? Also, when you run another xterm with, say, `xterm -u8 -fa "DejaVu Sans Mono"`, is `echo -e "\xE2\x98\xA0"` display the unicode character?

Comment: @apaul `xterm` is called from `~/.xinitrc` as per the op. but i will post the results of your questions there.

Comment: @mulllhausen Ok, since copy'n'paste works, that means xterm can handle unicode. It could be a font problem. Are you sure xterm is using "DejaVu Sans Mono" ? You can check it if you run in your xterm `lsof -p $PPID | grep fonts` and check the list of fonts that could be seen by xterm with `fc-list`.

Comment: @apaul i have added the info you requested

Comment: @mulllhausen Thx. As you can see, for some reason, xterm doesn't load the right font. It loads an iso-8859-1 one (which contains "é", that's why you can see it). Honestly, I don't know why. Can you run `xterm -class Foo -name foo -u8 -fa "DejaVu Sans Mono:style=Book"` ? (here we set a dummy class and name so it won't load the `XTerm*` resources.)

Comment: @apaul it works! i will post again in the op. and i will extend the question a little bit now

Answer (score 7):

***Writing in 2016, talking about xterm patch #278 (released in 2012):***

xterm uses a single font, rather than font *sets* which are supported by several other terminals.  The pseudo-graphic characters in this (pasted from xterm):

```
⎛     ⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽   ⎞
⎜    ╱    3     ⎟
⎜   ╱    x      ⎟
⎜  ╱   ───── , 1⎟
⎝╲╱    x + 1    ⎠
```

are **not** provided by the TypeType font specified here:

```
xterm.vt100.faceName: Terminus
xterm.vt100.faceSize: 14
```

Other terminals, given that font would provide those characters from *another* font.

The way to make xterm work is

- specify a font which does cover all of the characters needed, and
- tell it to use UTF-8 encoding.

The latter is addressed for most users by the default setting of the `locale` resource: xterm will (usually) use UTF-8 encoding.  But the default behavior is VT100-compatible, hence the use of ISO-8859-1 compatible fonts.

- Terminus uses more glyphs than that, but falls **far** short of covering all pseudo-graphics in Unicode.
- The ones that display as `n` are U+239B, U+239C, U+239D, U+239E, U+23A0.
- The version of Terminus in Debian 7 (and Debian testing) has less than 256 glyphs and happens to show `n` as described in the question.

That happens because (although xterm knows that the glyphs are missing), it has printed the string using the font, assuming that (like *most* other fonts) missing entries will be shown as *blanks*.  In this case, the freetype library seems to be *mapping* the low-order byte of the Unicode values into the range that Terminus supports.  That happens to fall in a range that the font displays as **`n`** (for "no such character"):

[image]

The quick workaround uses the `uxterm` script, which selects a different font and ensures that UTF-8 encoding is used.

Further reading:

- [**`uxterm`** - X terminal emulator for Unicode (UTF-8) environments](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/uxterm.html)
- [UXTerm.ad](https://github.com/andreasjansson/xhrrmm/blob/master/UXTerm.ad) (X application resources used for `uxterm`)
- [Terminus Font Home Page](http://terminus-font.sourceforge.net/)

> Terminus Font is a clean, fixed width bitmap font, designed for long (8 and more hours per day) work with computers. Version 4.40 contains **1241** characters, covers about 120 language sets and supports ISO8859-1/2/5/7/9/13/15/16, Paratype-PT154/PT254, KOI8-R/U/E/F, Esperanto, many IBM, Windows and Macintosh code pages, as well as the IBM VGA, vt100 and xterm pseudographic characters.

***The above was talking about xterm [patch #278](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_278) which was four years old in 2016.***  Development of xterm is ongoing, and beginning with [patch #338](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_338) (late 2018) there is support for TrueType fontsets.  Here is a screenshot using the OP's resource-settings from xterm [patch #342](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_342) (#343 will probably be out "soon"):

[image: screenshot from xterm #342]

Using the [`-report-fonts`](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#OPTIONS:-report-fonts) option, I see that it loaded these font-files (treating *bold/italic* as the "same" as *normal*, and using a ***second*** font for the special characters):

```
    file=/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc/ter-u18n\_iso-8859-1.pcf.gz              
    file=/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc/ter-u18b\_iso-8859-1.pcf.gz              
    file=/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc/ter-u18n\_iso-8859-1.pcf.gz              
    file=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf
```

The actual number of fonts depends on what you want to do.  In testing the existing range of Unicode values, it may use a couple of dozen fonts.

Comment: Have you got a plan to add support for fallback to other fonts on missing characters in xterm?

Comment: I'm short on round-tuits :-(  Font-sets would be nice, but take a couple of months...

Comment: A couple of months still seems a good estimate (I'm about 2/3 through that).

Answer (score 6):

Solutions from the comments:

- `uxterm`
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>RightClick (context menu) and UTF-8 encoding.
- `xterm -u8`
- X resources: use a [font specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_logical_font_description) with character set and econding fields set to `-iso10646-1`

For example, for `xterm` (X-class `Xterm`) and the Terminus font, you might add to ~/.Xresources

```
XTerm*font: -*-terminus-medium-r-normal--18-*-*-*-*-*-iso10646-1
```

To find the fonts and their font specs installed on your system see `/usr/share/fonts/*/*.dir` files. After editting `~/.Xresources`, load them with `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources`.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I, too haven't been able to get unicode support properly configured in `xterm`. As a workaround, I ended up installing `rxvt`, which is available from *rpmforge* on EL distros.  There's also a **unicode-256color** version of the program, which works great for me.  Here's the description:

```
Name        : rxvt
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 18
Version     : 2.7.10
Release     : 2.el7.rf
Size        : 326 k
Repo        : rpmforge
Summary     : Color VT102 terminal emulator for the X Window System
URL         : http://www.rxvt.org/
License     : GPL
Description : Rxvt is a color VT102 terminal emulator for the X Window System. Rxvt
            : is intended to be an xterm replacement for users who don't need the
            : more esoteric features of xterm, like Tektronix 4014 emulation,
            : session logging and toolkit style configurability. Since it does not
            : support those features, rxvt uses much less swap space than xterm
            : uses. This is a significant advantage on a machine which is serving a
            : large number of X sessions.
```

[ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Rxvt-unicode) has useful information as always on configuration and use-cases.

Comment: i now use `rxvt-unicode` too

Comment: errgh...so, my answer was a viable solution/workaround?

Comment: i guess so. i'd still like to know if there's a way to fix xterm though

Answer (score 0):

What about using TrueType fonts like below ? I can't get working standard `-fn *-*-...` option with xterm, but this works perfectly.

```
xterm -fa 'Inconsolata' -fs 12
```

Inconsolata fonts can be downloaded [here](https://www.levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html)