# Cyrillics in xmonad over Arch

Tags: arch-linux, fonts, xmonad

Setup:

```
$ cat /root/xmonad.hs 
import XMonad
import XMonad.Config.Desktop

main = xmonad desktopConfig
    { terminal = "xterm"
    , modMask  = mod4Mask
    }

$ cat ~/.profile 
TZ='Europe/Sofia'; export TZ
setxkbmap -layout "us,bg(phonetic)" -option "grp:alt_shift_toggle" &
```

Problem:
Although Firefox, for example, accepts the cyrillic input, my terminal doesn't. When I switch to `bg` keyboard layout, no key produces output (enter, space still work). Files with cyrillics in them display like this:

```
\chapter{               ^a      }
%   ^|         ^b               ^`
%   ^z         ^g         ^a   ^b               ^b    >
%   ^=   ^`                     ^b                    >
%                           ^f         ^b             >
%   ^w                ^a                   3    ^b    >
%   ^w                ^a                   5    ^b    >
%\\
\begin{multicols}{2}
\race{Homo Sapiens}{0}
```

Inadequate solutions:

- change terminal to `rxvt-unicode` or `gnome-terminal` or `xterm -u8`
- install `xorg-fonts-cyrillic` and `terminus-cyrillic`
- change the locale to `bg_BG.utf8` from the default locale `C`

None of those result in cyrillic characters being typed.

On locales:

```
$ locale
LANG=bg_BG.utf8
LC_CTYPE="bg_BG.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="bg_BG.utf8"
LC_TIME="bg_BG.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="bg_BG.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="bg_BG.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="bg_BG.utf8"
LC_PAPER="bg_BG.utf8"
LC_NAME="bg_BG.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="bg_BG.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="bg_BG.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="bg_BG.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="bg_BG.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

doesn't help and even scrambles **some** of the ascii text to e.g.

```
$ nohup: Ð²Ñ
Ð¾Ð´ÑÑ ÑÐµ Ð¿ÑÐµÐ½ÐµÐ±ÑÐµÐ³Ð²Ð°, Ð° Ð¸Ð·Ñ
Ð¾Ð´ÑÑ ÑÐµ Ð½Ð°ÑÐ¾ÑÐ²Ð° ÐºÑÐ¼ â
```

Doing an objectdump on

```
%Правото на две расови умения на 5, без да е нужно да покриват изисквания, без точките да се плащат от (5 * Ум), струва една точка.  \\
%Човеците имат всикчи показатели 1 - 10.  \\
%За всеки 3 точки по максимуми над 10, расата струва още една точка.  \\
```

results in

```
$ od -tx1 -c races.txt
0000000  25  d0  9f  d1  80  d0  b0  d0  b2  d0  be  d1  82  d0  be  20
          % 320 237 321 200 320 260 320 262 320 276 321 202 320 276    
0000020  d0  bd  d0  b0  20  d0  b4  d0  b2  d0  b5  20  d1  80  d0  b0
        320 275 320 260     320 264 320 262 320 265     321 200 320 260
0000040  d1  81  d0  be  d0  b2  d0  b8  20  d1  83  d0  bc  d0  b5  d0
        321 201 320 276 320 262 320 270     321 203 320 274 320 265 320
0000060  bd  d0  b8  d1  8f  20  d0  bd  d0  b0  20  35  2c  20  d0  b1
        275 320 270 321 217     320 275 320 260       5   ,     320 261
0000100  d0  b5  d0  b7  20  d0  b4  d0  b0  20  d0  b5  20  d0  bd  d1
        320 265 320 267     320 264 320 260     320 265     320 275 321
0000120  83  d0  b6  d0  bd  d0  be  20  d0  b4  d0  b0  20  d0  bf  d0
        203 320 266 320 275 320 276     320 264 320 260     320 277 320
0000140  be  d0  ba  d1  80  d0  b8  d0  b2  d0  b0  d1  82  20  d0  b8
        276 320 272 321 200 320 270 320 262 320 260 321 202     320 270
0000160  d0  b7  d0  b8  d1  81  d0  ba  d0  b2  d0  b0  d0  bd  d0  b8
        320 267 320 270 321 201 320 272 320 262 320 260 320 275 320 270
0000200  d1  8f  2c  20  d0  b1  d0  b5  d0  b7  20  d1  82  d0  be  d1
        321 217   ,     320 261 320 265 320 267     321 202 320 276 321
0000220  87  d0  ba  d0  b8  d1  82  d0  b5  20  d0  b4  d0  b0  20  d1
        207 320 272 320 270 321 202 320 265     320 264 320 260     321
0000240  81  d0  b5  20  d0  bf  d0  bb  d0  b0  d1  89  d0  b0  d1  82
        201 320 265     320 277 320 273 320 260 321 211 320 260 321 202
0000260  20  d0  be  d1  82  20  28  35  20  2a  20  d0  a3  d0  bc  29
            320 276 321 202       (   5       *     320 243 320 274   )
0000300  2c  20  d1  81  d1  82  d1  80  d1  83  d0  b2  d0  b0  20  d0
          ,     321 201 321 202 321 200 321 203 320 262 320 260     320
0000320  b5  d0  b4  d0  bd  d0  b0  20  d1  82  d0  be  d1  87  d0  ba
        265 320 264 320 275 320 260     321 202 320 276 321 207 320 272
0000340  d0  b0  2e  20  20  5c  5c  0a  25  d0  a7  d0  be  d0  b2  d0
        320 260   .           \   \  \n   % 320 247 320 276 320 262 320
0000360  b5  d1  86  d0  b8  d1  82  d0  b5  20  d0  b8  d0  bc  d0  b0
        265 321 206 320 270 321 202 320 265     320 270 320 274 320 260
0000400  d1  82  20  d0  b2  d1  81  d0  b8  d0  ba  d1  87  d0  b8  20
        321 202     320 262 321 201 320 270 320 272 321 207 320 270    
0000420  d0  bf  d0  be  d0  ba  d0  b0  d0  b7  d0  b0  d1  82  d0  b5
        320 277 320 276 320 272 320 260 320 267 320 260 321 202 320 265
0000440  d0  bb  d0  b8  20  31  20  2d  20  31  30  2e  20  20  5c  5c
        320 273 320 270       1       -       1   0   .           \   \
0000460  0a  25  d0  97  d0  b0  20  d0  b2  d1  81  d0  b5  d0  ba  d0
         \n   % 320 227 320 260     320 262 321 201 320 265 320 272 320
0000500  b8  20  33  20  d1  82  d0  be  d1  87  d0  ba  d0  b8  20  d0
        270       3     321 202 320 276 321 207 320 272 320 270     320
0000520  bf  d0  be  20  d0  bc  d0  b0  d0  ba  d1  81  d0  b8  d0  bc
        277 320 276     320 274 320 260 320 272 321 201 320 270 320 274
0000540  d1  83  d0  bc  d0  b8  20  d0  bd  d0  b0  d0  b4  20  31  30
        321 203 320 274 320 270     320 275 320 260 320 264       1   0
0000560  2c  20  d1  80  d0  b0  d1  81  d0  b0  d1  82  d0  b0  20  d1
          ,     321 200 320 260 321 201 320 260 321 202 320 260     321
0000600  81  d1  82  d1  80  d1  83  d0  b2  d0  b0  20  d0  be  d1  89
        201 321 202 321 200 321 203 320 262 320 260     320 276 321 211
0000620  d0  b5  20  d0  b5  d0  b4  d0  bd  d0  b0  20  d1  82  d0  be
        320 265     320 265 320 264 320 275 320 260     321 202 320 276
0000640  d1  87  d0  ba  d0  b0  2e  20  20  5c  5c  0a
        321 207 320 272 320 260   .           \   \  \n
0000654
```

and the file is

```
$ file races.tex 
races.tex: LaTeX document, UTF-8 Unicode text
```

Some more attempts:

- `showconsolefont` # prints the current font
- `localectl`  # prints the current font name
- `setfont Cyr_a8x14  # requires root; from /usr/share/kbd/unimaps`

Now it seems to work. I think `setfont` provided the cyrilic characters in the font. Sadly it doesn't work for the Virtual Terminals.

```
$ localectl
System Locale: LANG=en_US.utf8
VC Kemap: bg_pho-utf8
X11 Layout: bg,us
X11 Model: pc105
X11 Variant: ,phonetic
X11 Options: terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,grp:shifts_toggle,grp_led:scroll
```

Comment: Please add more details to your question: What exactly means "your teminal doesn't accept cyrillic input"? Is it a display problem only? Can you create files that contain cyrillic characters? What locale do you use? **Why** are the "inadequate solutions" not usable. See also the answers to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/196152/330217

Comment: @Bodo thanks! Better?

Comment: So with "inadequate solutions" you mean that you tried these solutions and it did not work? (I misunderstood this part of your original question.) Do you get the same result with these attempted solutions? How exactly did you try to change the locale? I still want to find out if it is a display problem and/or an input problem. Please try in a terminal something like this: type `echo 'бгдф' > test.txt` even if the cyrillic characters don't appear, and then `od -tx1 -c test.txt` and show the output. (The input should contain a few cyrillic characters that don't look like latin characters.)

Comment: When I try to paste your command through the primary buffer (ctrl+insert OR middle mouse button) in xterm, the result is `echo '####' > test.txt`. The locale I changed  via `/etc/locale.conf`.

Comment: Don't paste the command. Type it and switch your keyboard to cyrillic for a few cyrillic characters. Then show the commands you typed and the output of the `od` command in your question.

Comment: If xterm's running in POSIX (C) locale, the `-u8` option won't do much for you (as illustrated in the '####' comment).  The `uxterm` script attempts to ensure that the locale is UTF-8 while also setting the resources and options needed.

Comment: @Bodo to reiterate, when I "switch your keyboard to cyrillic for a few cyrillic characters", and this is true under all permutations of the "Solution points", and type ... nothing happens. Only enter, spacebar, escape - respond at those times.

Comment: I asked for the output of the `od` command, not for a description what happens in the terminal window when you type cyrillic characters. You should add all requested information to the question instead of answering in comments. You should add all details to avoid further questions. For Example: Are you sure your change in `/etc/locale.conf` was effective for your test? Did you reboot the system or restart any processes?